# Passing and displaying the ArrayList result from Intent

Tags: android, arrays, image, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to pass **`arraylist` object values** from one `activity` to another, however after completing the process the result is blank screen. What am i doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Putting the values into the intent:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            Mahad.class);
    //
    in.putExtra("identifier",identifier);               
    in.putExtra("price",price);
    in.putExtra("bedrooms",bedrooms);
    in.putExtra("address",address);
    in.putExtra("property",propType);
    //in.putExtra("Property url : " + image, 0);

    startActivity(in);
}
```

Displaying the values from my other activity:

```
   Intent in = getIntent();          
   identifier = in.getStringArrayListExtra("identifier");   
    TextView lbli = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.identifier_i);     
    lbli.setTag(identifier);
```

I also pass an image in the same way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: identifier is list??? list of primitive or list of object??

Comment: Zortkun,its a list of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use`Intent.putStringArrayListExtra("identifier")`  and access the data as you have done

Comment: Hey man thanks,I have tried almost very thing and my list is not displayed into the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you have a list like this:

```
List<Identifires> identifire = new List<Identifires>();
```

make Identifires class serializable. and use `in.getSerializableExtra` to get value. however you can use `parcelling` too.

Comment: I'm currently doing this, private ArrayList<String> identif = new ArrayList<String>(); is your suggestion differ? pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> TextView lbli = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.identifier_i);
>       lbli.setTag(identifier);
>   i think u are doing a mistake. you cannot use "setTag" to settext and also you cannot set an array list to a textview only one item of the array list can be set like

```
lbli.setText(identifier[1]);
```